# What is the conventional notation for these logic statements?

Tags: logic, notation

When I studied chemical engineering I often found the need to rewrite lecture notes, handouts and books in order to gain a thorough understanding of the subject I was reading. As much as time permitted I used to draw mindmaps of the reading material combining the symbols on the left in the image below:

[image: Short hand notation for logic statements]

The first ones are probably known, but some of these may need some explanation. I will list all of them with my own explantions to make clear what I mean.

1. B is a part of A. B is a subset of A. B is a property of A.
2. B is partly a part of A. B is a almost a subset of A. B is to a very small degree a property of A.
3. A equals B. A and B are the same thing.
4. B is a consequence of A. If A happens then B happens as a consequence.
5. A becomes B. First there is only A, later there is only B.
6. This describes a process or a verb. A is put into B. Example: A reactant (A) is fed into a reactor (B).
7. A affects property B and causes a decrease, and B is a property of some other object as drawn in 1.
8. A affects property B and causes an increase, and B is a property of some other object as drawn in 1.
9. A intends to cause B to come into existance. Example: A company (A) strives to create profit (B).
10. A strives/wants/intends to become B. Example: One strives to keep the concentration of reactant (A) in a reactor to be 0.1 mol/liter (B).

> What are the conventional mathematical names and symbols used to denote these relations above?

Edit 19.5.2013: Just as an example I analyzed a sentence taken from a paper by Ernest Davis about technological singularity:
[image: Singularity-example]

It is not perfect though.

Comment: Depends on what kind of objects $A,B$ are. For 1., 2., 3. you seem to speak of sets (subsets, intersections and non-disjointness, equality), for 4. of propositions (entailment). From 5. on something more complex is needed to model this as these involve time dependence - as math is basically independent of time and causality, no "basic" objects are applicable.

Comment: Ok, Thank you for the comment. I was not aware of math being independent of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. subset of: $B \subset A$ *(or member of: $B \in A$)*
2. intersection: $B \wedge  A$ *(it would require several statements to say "A and B are not null, they are not equal, their intersection is not null")*
3. equal to: $B = A$
4. implies (if/then): $A \implies B$
5. function of: $B = f(A)$ *(however, things do not "become" other things. You can apply transformations to get a new thing, but the original thing still exists.)*
6. *In general, a given thing is either in a set, or not, without moving.*
7. negative derivative: $B(t) = -\frac{\partial A}{\partial t}$
8. positive derivative: $B(t) = \frac{\partial A}{\partial t}$
9. *I'm iffy about "become" or "put", but there is definitely no math symbol for intent.*